# ProgressMonitor for OSGi services

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, progressmonitor

I wanted to implement ProgressMonitor for an OSGi services.
I understand the protocol of IProgessMonitor and how it should be used within service.

However, I do not know how the implementation of IProgressMonitor would look like.
Also, how do I get/read the status of the progress in case of OSGi services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no progress or status indicator for an OSGi service.  If you wish to put something in place for long running calls you will have to do it in an application specific way as there is no standard for this.

A blocking call will return when it is done, if it is a non-blocking call, then it may provide some sort of callback or event based response, but again, that would be application specific.

IProgressMonitor is an Eclipse thing, which has not direct correlation to OSGi.